# Why private static variable becomes null at some point and what can I do to resolve?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, google-api

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

On first page load, **result is not null** but at some point, after some time, when Gmail action is called from Javascript, **it becomes null** (after one of these 10 minute interval calls). It is declared as private static, initialized in Index action and should be alive (not null) all the time.

*I managed to catch it by leaving the app running it in a Debug mode for a few hours.*

Thank you.

Comment: using static fields is a bad practice to keep something in web apps. Please use .net cache or session instead. I think in your case value of that static field may be disposed by garbage collector. Actually you can check it by some profiler or use custom disposable type and and try to log that via during disposing.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just save the cancellation token and recreate the "result" instance on Gmail() function call ?

private CancellationToken token = token; (on index call)

public ActionResult Gmail() {
  result = new Authresult(token);
  ...
}

Comment: Because I have no idea what you mean by that. I don't understand what it has to do with cancellation token. We are talking about Google's OAuth 2.0, right? There is no such thing as Authresult(token) in Google's OAuth 2.0.

Comment: I was shortening it for you, i will edit my answer to be more accurate in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose the problem first it is work to double check whether you are accessing the variable in the same AppDomain where it was initialized - to check this you could just add some logging. It could be possible that this is a different AppDomain, because some event triggered IIS AppDomain pool recycling.
If it is the case, then you have 2 options:

- either store the state using another mechanism or
- have lazy initialization on demand with a null check, so the value can be initialized each time it's needed

Comment: I think that could be it - the AppDomain IIS pool recycling. I have Re-attach extension installed, and I used it to attach to IIS pool, and left it VS running in debug mode. After some time I came back and found it was no longer in debug mode. It was weird, So I tried to re-attach again using that extension and it threw an error message that it was unable to find that pool anymore. I am thinking to use session to store that object instead of static field, maybe I will use Cache, but not sure what is more reliable - Session or Cache?

Comment: @monstro: Cache data is available for anyone how knows a key. Session data is available inside specific request only. So, if you need to have different values for different users - use session. If you need to have shared value between all users - use Cache.

Comment: Session can expire and the data will be lost, whereas Cache data could be accessible from other sessions, which could pose a security threat.
It all depends on your requirements.
I would read this first before opting for session https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx, and if it's not a good fit - explore other options, which are briefly mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx